# PHP script displaying a blank page

Tags: php, mysql, database, select, echo

This is my script and it's displaying a blank, I have no idea what the problem is. HELP!!!! #new to PHP

```
 <?php include "connection.php"; 
    // Get the ID from URL.
   if(isset($_GET['id']));
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $query="SELECT * FROM module WHERE id= '$id'"; 
    $result= mysqli_query($m, $query); 
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
     $title=$row['title']; 
     $level=$row['level']; 
     $credits=$row['credits'];
     $school=$row['school']; 
 echo $title. " " . $level. " " . $credits. "<br />"; 
 }    
 ?>
```

Error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id= 'Careers'' at line 1

Comment: Add  `ini_set('display_errors', 1);ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);error_reporting(E_ALL);` on the top of your code and tell us if there's any errors being reported. Also, what are the contents of `$_GET`.

Comment: Can you make sure that connection.php works fine?

Comment: You're right ! I delete it to avoid others to make this msitake

Comment: connection.php work fine, this is the error its coming up with You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id= 'Careers'' at line 1

Comment: @user5579012 did you not see the answer I posted almost an hour ago? http://stackoverflow.com/a/36499440/1415724

Comment: @user5579012 and why is `Careers` used as an id? you probably removed the quotes in here `WHERE id= '$id'`

Comment: @user5579012 the error you posted, does NOT support the question, not with the answer I've given you.

Comment: this is my query,  $query="SELECT id, title  module WHERE id= '$id'";

Comment: @user5579012 That wasn't what you posted in your original question.  You posted `SELECT * FROM module WHERE id= '$id'`. Reload my answer under **Edit:**. http://stackoverflow.com/a/36499440/1415724

Comment: The problem was with the query, I changed it a bit and I was also selecting a wrong table, this query work fine ,$query="SELECT id, dept, overview FROM course WHERE careers= $id";  thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One obvious problem here is that you've included an "end of statement" character being a semi-colon.

The semi-colon (if that isn't a typo), is doing just that, "ending" the statement.

```
if(isset($_GET['id']));
                       ^ right there.
```

It should be a brace `{` for it instead and to read as:

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
```

and there should be a closing brace `}` for that conditional statement for it.

Sidenote: The semi-colon  is considered a valid character in PHP, which won't throw you an error for it, should the GET array have a value.

However, you should check for errors for the rest of your code.

Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, 
 as well as `or die(mysqli_error($m))` to `mysqli_query()`.

While making sure you are indeed using the MySQLi_ API to connect with (*different MySQL APIs do not intermix*) and that the GET array has a value.

---

Here's a rewrite, and assuming a successful DB connection using the [MySQLi_ API](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) for it.

```
<?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

if(isset($_GET['id'])){
   $id = $_GET['id'];
} else{
    echo "ID is not set. You need to investigate it.";
    exit; // This will stop your script, dead in its tracks.
}

$query="SELECT * FROM module WHERE id= '$id'"; 
$result= mysqli_query($m, $query) or die(mysqli_error($m)); 

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
 $title=$row['title']; 
 $level=$row['level']; 
 $credits=$row['credits'];
 $school=$row['school']; 

    echo $title. " " . $level. " " . $credits. "<br />"; 
}
```

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

---

**Edit:**

Taken from comments:

> *"this is my query, $query="SELECT id, title module WHERE id= '$id'"; – user5579012 38 mins ago"*

[Link to that comment...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36499229/php-script-displaying-a-blank-page/36499440#comment60608932_36499229)

That isn't what was posted in your original question.

You posted `SELECT * FROM module WHERE id= '$id'`.

You have a syntax error here, being a missing comma after `title`.

It should read as:

```
$query="SELECT id, title, module WHERE id= '$id'";
```

All columns need to be seperated by commas but not the last one being `module` here.

Comment: The error posted, does NOT support the question, not with the answer I've given you and what you have for code and the rewrite I have written for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure everything is ok. Echo errors if possible.

```
<?php include "connection.php"; 
// Get the ID from URL.
 if(isset($_GET['id'])){
$id = $_GET['id'];
$query="SELECT * FROM module WHERE id= '$id'"; 
$result= mysqli_query($m, $query);

if($result){ //query is ok
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){//check if a record exists

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
                 $title=$row['title']; 
                 $level=$row['level']; 
                 $credits=$row['credits'];
                 $school=$row['school']; 
            echo $title. " " . $level. " " . $credits. "<br />"; 
        }
     }else{ //no result found
         echo "no results found!";
     }
  }else{ //some error in querying
    echo mysqli_error($m);
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: Did you even test this code? Hint: it will never get as far as checking $result.

Comment: after using the code you provide me with I now get this error,  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id= 'Careers'' at line 1

Comment: yeah I tested and its returned no result found

Comment: The problem was with the query, I changed it a bit and I was also selecting a wrong table, this query work ,$query="SELECT id, dept, overview FROM course WHERE careers= $id";  thank for the help!!!